# Two sorting / filtering methods used at the same time Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two methods - `sort` and `more_than`, Here is my JS:

```js
const originalData = [{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "ASD",
    "number": 50,
    "src": "https://cloudfour.com/examples/img-currentsrc/images/kitten-small.png"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "FGH",
    "number": 150,
    "src": "https://cloudfour.com/examples/img-currentsrc/images/kitten-small.png"
  }
]
const data = [...originalData]
const info_container = document.querySelector('.info-container')

const sort = () => {
  const newData = data.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(a.id) - parseFloat(b.id))
  fetchData(newData)
}

const more_than = (e) => {
  if (e) {
    const newData = data.filter((a) => {
      return parseFloat(a.number) > parseFloat(e)
    })
    fetchData(newData)
  } else return
}

const clear_filters = () => {
  const radio = document.querySelector('input[name="sort"]')

  radio.checked = false
  fetchData(originalData)
}


const fetchData = (data) => {
  info_container.innerHTML = "";
  data.forEach((item, index) => {
    const img = document.createElement("img");
    const title = document.createElement('h3')

    const node = document.createTextNode(item.src);
    const node_title = document.createTextNode(item.title)

    title.appendChild(node_title)
    img.src = item.src

    info_container.appendChild(title)
    info_container.appendChild(img);

  })
}
window.onload = function() {
  fetchData(originalData)
}
```

```html
<div><input type="radio" name="sort" onclick="sort()" />sort</div>
<div>More <input min="1" max="1000" oninput="more_than(value)" type="number" name="pages" /> than</div>
<div><button onclick="clear_filters()">Clear</button></div>
<div class="info-container">

</div>
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/HFuL37jL9ZHbvI2lib6t?p=preview

I want to use them in the same time. Now my `sort` function disappears after `more_than` and vice versa. How to fix that? 
Thanks for answers in advance!

Comment: _...disappears_? Could you be a little more descriptive as to what you mean by that?

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb Type "150" in more_than input, then click "sort". more_than function disappears, and there is only sorting

Comment: You need to be more specific, you want to run them both at the same time? or you want both functions combined?

Comment: @AndrewDaly i want both functions combined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have a kind of "meta" instance which allows you to keep the application state intact. That means, you need a way to keep the user selection stored inside variables. In the example below, `Store` acts as a repository for your data which also knows how many "pages" should be displayed as well as if the data should be sorted by `.id`. Calling `.getItems()` returns you a list of sorted/unsorted values, optionally filtered by "pages". Please note that `Store` doesn't *alter* the original data. It instead returns a new *copy* of the original data every time you call `.getItems()`.

```js
const originalData = [{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "ASD",
    "number": 50,
    "src": "https://cloudfour.com/examples/img-currentsrc/images/kitten-small.png"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "FGH",
    "number": 150,
    "src": "https://cloudfour.com/examples/img-currentsrc/images/kitten-small.png"
  }
]



const Store = data => {
  let __sorted = false;
  let __pages = 0;
  
  const _Store = {
    sorted() {
      __sorted = true;
      return _Store;
    },
    unsorted() {
      __sorted = false;
      return _Store;
    },
    setPages(num) {
      if (typeof num === 'number' && !isNaN(num)) {
        __pages = Math.abs(num); // ensure we have a positive number
      }
      return _Store;
    },
    unsetPages() {
      __pages = 0; // revert back to default
      return _Store;
    },
    getItems() {
      let items = [...data];
      if (__sorted) {
        return __pages <= 0 ? items.sort((a, b) => Number(a.id) - Number(b.id)) :
               /* else */     items.filter(a => Number(a.number) >= __pages).
                                    sort((a, b) => Number(a.id) - Number(b.id))
      }
      return __pages <= 0 ? items :
             /* else */     items.filter(a => Number(a.number) >= __pages);
    }
  };
  
  return _Store;
};



const dataStore = Store(originalData);
const $checkSort = document.querySelector('input[name="sort"]');
const $inputPages = document.querySelector('input[name="pages"]');
const $resetFilters = document.querySelector('#filter-reset');
const $output = document.querySelector('.info-container')

function onCheckSorted (event) {
  if (event.target.checked) {
    dataStore.sorted();
  } else {
    dataStore.unsorted();
  }
  
  show();
}

function onChangePages (event) {
  let v = Number(event.target.value.trim());
  if (v && !isNaN(v)) {
    dataStore.setPages(v);
  } else {
    dataStore.unsetPages();
  }
  
  show();
}

function onClickReset () {
  $checkSort.checked = null; // update UI
  $inputPages.value = null;  // update UI

  dataStore.unsetPages().unsorted();
  show();
}

function show () {
  $output.innerHTML = "";
  dataStore.getItems().forEach((item, index) => {
    const img = document.createElement("img");
    const title = document.createElement('h3')

    const node = document.createTextNode(item.src);
    const node_title = document.createTextNode(item.title)

    title.appendChild(node_title)
    img.src = item.src

    $output.appendChild(title)
    $output.appendChild(img);
  });
}



$checkSort.addEventListener('change', onCheckSorted);
$inputPages.addEventListener('input', onChangePages);
$resetFilters.addEventListener('click', onClickReset);

// kick off
show();
```

```html
<div><input type="checkbox" name="sort" />sort</div>
<div>More <input min="1" max="1000" type="number" name="pages" /> than</div>
<div><button id="filter-reset">Clear</button></div>
<div class="info-container">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you help me one more time? Do you know how to add another sort function, to sort by title?

Comment: on click another radio button